# How to add CPU core licenses (I've already purchased) to Windows Server Standard 2019?

Tags: windows-server-2019, multi-core, microsoft

I have purchased a 24-core server (Dual 12 core CPU's).  I installed Windows Server Standard 2019, which comes by default with 16 cores.

I want to use the additional 8 CPU cores, so I purchased two additional 4-core licenses for Windows Server 2019 Standard.  When I received them, there are no instructions on how to activate the addition 8 cores from the two four core licenses.  Cumulatively I've now spent about 8 hours digging through menus, googling, digging down through the Microsoft website and have come up empty.  I tried to call Microsoft support but spent hours and did not manage to get through to a human on Server 2019.

It must be so simple.  Can anyone please tell me how I can activate the additional 8 cores now that I have purchased the official Microsoft four core licenses from NewEgg (reputable source)?

Answer (score 2):

Licensing is a legal and logical construct. It doesn't allow or deny you from physically using any or all of the CPU cores on the server. There's no license "activation" as far as the CPU is concerned.

You "activate" Windows with a Product Key, but that Product Key has nothing to do with having the proper per core licenses.

Comment: Thank you joeqwerty.  So the implications are that I spent $800 for ‘core’ upgrades that have no way of actually being applied to my windows installation:  it is just a certificate to keep in the drawer in case my home hobby server gets audited?

So this means that all 24 cores will continue to work at full capacity on my 16-core windows server 2019 standard license?  

Sure was confusing up front before I purchased the ‘extra core licenses’.  Wish I hadn’t wasted the money for a hobby server.

Comment: You could have just installed the trial version and ran that for 180 days. Also, you might look into a Microsoft Action Pack subscription as part of the Microsoft Partner Network (which you can enroll in). MAPS will give you internal use licenses for Windows Server, Exchange Server, Visual Studio, etc., and will give you a limited number of Office 365 licenses (5 of Office 365 E3), as well as $100.00 of monthly Azure credits. IMO, it's well worth the $475.00 (plus tax) yearly MAPS subscription price.

Answer (score 0):

To be as Easy as possible, the *correctly* Licensing of any Microsoft Products Specially while Using any Virtualization may get terrifically Horrible and a catastrophe in many ways, I respond to your question in - GENERALLY

You told that you already own a Windows Server XXXX License. That's Good, the only thing is, it restricts you (Logically) to use only XX Amount of CPU's or Sockets.

If in case you use more, as your Current License Allows you, you are forced to buy additional Licenses. This does not mean, that you currently used OS will restrict or does not use the extra cores, they are just not licensed. That Means you are bad in the sight of Microsoft. :-)

A Short Instruction, (and I mean really a Basic Overview) can take [this PDF-File from Microsoft](https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/D/4/3D42BDC2-6725-4B29-B75A-A5B04179958B/Licensing_brief_PLT_Introduction_to_Microsoft_Core_licensing.pdf)

Sometimes it might be Usefully, to use a Higher Version as it might be less Cost-Intensive over time seen, to License Correctly.

Remind that, some Versions have even Restrictions about features or with them to use. But this will be too much to explain here.

So, my Conclusion about this?
In my 20 Years of Working as an Onsite-Administrator, I sometimes suggested to use just a Small Linux Server instead of Windows for Cost-Saving. Sometimes you don't or won't have this option, but can take a Standard Windows Installation even it's not the best but cost-effective option. However, it regards all the time to the Money and of the Company and as also the Responsive Sponsor.